# Setting a proxy for specific url in android application

Tags: java, android, proxy, httpurlconnection, vpn

`enter code here`I am using from [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) in my project. How can I set `proxy` when I am using from `OneSignal`?

Bellow is my code but use from internet without `proxy`:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String userName = "userNAme";
                String pass = "Pass";
                Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

                    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return (new PasswordAuthentication(userName, pass.toCharArray()));
                    }
                };
                Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
                Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("xx.xxx.xx", 443));
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://onesignal.com/").openConnection(proxy);
                connection.usingProxy();
                connection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
                connection.connect();
                if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    OneSignal.startInit(App.this)
                            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                            .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new NotificationReceivedHandler())
                            .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationOpenedHandler(App.this))
                            .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                            .init();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }

        }
    }).start();
```